# js wont show result of calculation

Tags: javascript

Quick newbie question, i'm sure it is simple to you, but i cant get my head around to figure out why my code wont work. Checked online, seems that i'm doing everything fine, but still wont work... All i'm trying to do, is to make simple calc and display that in diff field. I have tryed external and internal JS.
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(){
    var a = document.calculate.first.value;
    var b = document.calculate.second.value;
    var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    document.calculate.result.value = c;
    }
</script>


<body>
    <form name="calculate">
        <input type="text" name="first" size="5">
        <input type="text" name="second" size="5">
        <input type="button" onclick="calculate()">
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" size="5">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (onclick)
```

Give a different name to the form and the onclick handler! [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jMLLR/) is a test.

Comment: We can admit in this case the "Form" is not needed to only execute 'calcultate()'

Comment: kol, how do you get chrome to check your js file?

Comment: @MrPaulius I copied your code into jsFiddle, opened the console with F12, then pressed the Run button. Chrome wrote the error message into the console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(){
        var a = document.getElementById('first').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('second').value;
        var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        document.getElementById('result').value = c;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="calculateform">
            <input type="text" id="first" size="5">
            <input type="text" id="second" size="5">
            <input type="button" onclick="calculate()">
            <input type="text" id="result" id="result" size="5">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are using the same name for the form as for your js function. 
Working example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function calculate(){
        alert(document.calculatex.first.value);
        var a = document.calculatex.first.value;
        var b = document.calculatex.first.value;
        var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        document.calculatex.result.value= c;
     }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="calculatex">
        <input type="text" name="first" size="5"/>
        <input type="text" name="second" size="5"/>
        <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate();"/>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" size="5"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Have a look into JQuery library (convenient for getting/setting field values).